# JasperServer 6.4: Specify series type and yAxis

Tags: highcharts, series, jasperserver

Using JasperServer 6.4, hoping I don't have to resort to studio to achieve the following:

- I have a chart with 6 data series. I want the first three series to be
  stacked bar, and the last 3 to be lines.
- In JasperServer 6.4 I selected chart type Stacked Column Line.
- Currently the first 5 series are stacked bars on yAxis = 0, and the
  6th series is a line on yAxis=1.

How can I tell jasperserver to make the last three series type = line?

Amongst other things, i have tried:

- plotOptions.series: [{type: 'column', yAxis: 0}, {type: 'column', yAxis: 0}, {type: 'column', yAxis: 0}, {type: 'line', yAxis: 1},{type: 'line', yAxis: 1},{type: 'line', yAxis: 1}]
- series.type: ["line","line","line","column","column","column"]

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide full configuration of your chart.

Comment: @kamilkulig My chart is generated server-side, not in studio.
  - Type: StackedColumnLine. In Advanced formats i have plotOptions.column.stacking: "normal". plotOptions.line.connectNulls: "true". colors["blue","green","grey","blue","green","grey"]